# Clickonce SQL Server CE installation location

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, windows-8, sql-server-ce, clickonce

I am using Entity Framework migrations, SQL Server CE 4.0, and distribute through Clickonce.

In my `app.config`, the `datasource` is `DataSource=|DataDirectory|Mydb.sdf`.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyContext" connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|Mydb.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

When I deploy it to Windows XP and Windows 7, the database will deploy to something like below:

```
C:\Users\kev\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\8Y5K2R4J.AM9\Y3D5WADC.HAX\myapp..tion_ab2e572047b7b084_0001.0000_66744c6353cd31ca\Data
```

The problem is Windows 8 Smart screen prompted, and user click on continue to run anyway, the database is create in the `application(exe) directory`, and not the location above.

How can I explicit tell clickonce to create database in the directory above?

---

Found this:

It does not work because of Windows 8 smart screen.

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=920700

|DataDirectory| substitution string support
|DataDirectory| (enclosed in pipe symbols) is a substitution string that indicates the database path. Therefore, you do not have to include the full path in the code. When you include the full path in the code, you may experience problems because the full database path can be serialized in different locations. The |DataDirectory| substitution string also makes it easy to share a project and to deploy an application.

For example, if you include the full path in the code, the application can have the following connection string.

Data Source= c:\program files\MyApp\Mydb.sdf
If you use the |DataDirectory| substitution string, the application can have the following connection string.

Data Source = |DataDirectory|\Mydb.sdf
To set the DataDirectory property, call the AppDomain.SetData method. If you do not set the DataDirectory property, the following default rules are applied to access the database folder:•For applications that are put in a folder on the user's computer, the database folder uses the application folder.
•For applications that are running under ClickOnce, the database folder uses the specific data folder that is created. 
Note The .NET Compact Framework does not support the AppDomain.SetData method on Microsoft Windows Mobile-based devices. If an application calls the AppDomain.SetData method on a Windows Mobile-based device, you receive an error message.